# Windows Server 2008 r2 dsadd usercreation does not work

Tags: batch-file, command-line, active-directory, command-prompt

i made a batchfile that is supposed to create users from a txt file but somehow it seems to skip the (for /f .........) dsadd part :( am i doing something wrong?

It's Fixed thx :D

this is the working code

```
@echo off
cls
echo Creating Accounts
echo -----------------
for /F "tokens=1-2" %%A in (Users.txt) do dsadd user cn=%%A,ou=OU-%%B,dc=school,dc=local -disabled no -pwd Welkom01 -memberof cn=%%B,ou=OU-%%B,dc=school,dc=local -hmdir \\DC01\%%A$\Data -hmdrv S: -profile \\DC01\%%A$\Profile -canchpwd yes -pwdneverexpires yes
echo -----------------
pause
```

Comment: You forgot the `/F` switch: `for /F "tokens=1-2" %%A in ...`

Comment: thx for the response, I had that, this was the wrong code... oops.
but it still doens't work.

Answer (score 0):

{**ANSWERED**}

The right code is

```
@echo off
cls
echo Creating Accounts
echo -----------------
for /F "tokens=1-2" %%A in (Users.txt) do dsadd user cn=%%A,ou=OU-%%B,dc=school,dc=local -disabled no -pwd Welkom01 -memberof cn=%%B,ou=OU-%%B,dc=school,dc=local -hmdir \\DC01\%%A$\Data -hmdrv S: -profile \\DC01\%%A$\Profile -canchpwd yes -pwdneverexpires yes
echo -----------------
pause
```

the file got messed up becouse I made it with parts of other codes. :)